# How to optimize dragging on mobile devices using HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, animation, mobile, canvas

I am developing a web-app that uses dragging a handle over a constrained path (quarter of a circle). The tool is HTML5 canvas and the problem is bad responsiveness - the handle falls behind the finger , when dragging the handle with your finger. This happens on older mobile devices with slower processors. Is there any way make the sliding (look) smoother? I don't need coverage on all smartphones but the iPhone 2, 3 and some older android devices are really slow right now.

Are there any other approaches that I can use? CSS3 webkit?

An example of the slider (works with mobile devices only): http://jsfiddle.net/TtgYH/1/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width='300' height='500'
```

Comment: iPhone 2 and 3? These are sooo old now, no one expects them to be supported these days. The other issue, besides hardware, is that they obviously don't support the latest version of IOS which, as of version 5 and 6, canvas has seen some big improvements in performance.

Comment: old but still viable. we actually found a way to get closer to the native apps. 
phonegap or icenium is the solution